# Binding TextBox to Settings isn't working

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, textbox

i'm recenlty working with some WPF code and i have a big problem. I've added Setting generated by visual studio and i want to use it as binding in window. So i created something like that:

```
<TextBox VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Name="username_textbox"   Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource Settings}, Mode=TwoWay, Path=Default.Password}" />
```

Which is okay, when i declare at App.xaml:

```
<Application x:Class="BlinkLinkClient.App"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:properties="clr-namespace:BlinkLinkClient.Properties"
            ShutdownMode="OnExplicitShutdown">
   <Application.Resources>
       <ResourceDictionary>
           <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
              <ResourceDictionary Source="GeneralResourceDictionary.xaml" />
           </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
           <properties:Settings x:Key="Settings" />
       </ResourceDictionary>
   </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

But i found in web that method sometime could crash, so i used other method:

```
 <TextBox VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1" Name="password_textbox" Text="{Binding Source={x:Static properties:Settings.Default}, Path=password}" Grid.Column="1" />
```

Where my properies namespace is:

```
xmlns:properties="clr-namespace:BlinkLinkClient.Properties"
```

Error at output during binding

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Username' property not found on 'object' ''Settings' (HashCode=32985660)'. BindingExpression:Path=Username; DataItem='Settings' (HashCode=32985660); target element is 'TextBox' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')

Settings class (with only one prop, each of is similar):

```
namespace BlinkLinkClient {


    [global::System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute()]

    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute
    ("Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editors.SettingsDesigner.SettingsSingleFileGenerator", "12.0.0.0")]
    public partial class Settings : global::System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase {

    private static Settings defaultInstance = ((Settings)(global::System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.Synchronized(new Settings())));

    public static Settings Default {
        get {
            return defaultInstance;
        }
    }

    [global::System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute()]
    [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
    [global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("user@gmail.com")]
    public string Username {
        get {
            return ((string)(this["Username"]));
        }
        set {
            this["Username"] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Nothing is happen, data isn't stored or even shows up (i provide default values and it's setted in other code where i have full access to it). What i did wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The second method (`StaticExtension` to get `Settings` instance + `Binding` with a setting name as `Path`) is correct. The first method won't work, because it creates a separate instance of settings and has incorrect path (you can't bind to static properties).

Please check letter case. In the first example, the property is named `Password`, but it's `password` in the second example. Look for binding errors in the Output window. You can also try debugging with the `PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel` attached property.

Also, in order to save properties, you'll need to call `Save()` method somewhere. Binding will just change property values, it won't store them.

Comment: I added error message from output, also binding method changed to second. I changed props to capitalized, but error still arrives.

Comment: @DawidPura The error message clearly says that `Settings` class doesn't have `Username` property. Open the generated class and copy property name from there. Make sure you're using correct `Settings` class (there may be multiple).

Comment: only one settings class exists. I added Settings code with Username property.

Comment: @DawidPura See complete sample [So26566152WpfSettingsBinding.zip](http://www.mediafire.com/download/9frv8oybgb23jzg/So26566152WpfSettingsBinding.zip) — it does work. I still don't see output from tracing your binding on high level.